# Is it possible to write clean HTML code into robot framework test/suite documentation?

Tags: html, robotframework, robotframework-ide

everyone.

At the moment I am trying to update my test case/test suite [Documentation] in robot framework by adding different styles. I noticed, that there are separate section for **Documentation formatting** (https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#documentation-formatting) however, it looks a bit **limited**. And also, there is nothing mentioned about using raw html.

There are several keywords in builtIn library (example: log), that allows to use html entirely, so maybe there is also a way to use raw html in test/suite documentation?

What tried:
While trying to write html code in documentation, it is kept as simple string...

Thanks for response!